# C pass size of an array to another c file variable

Tags: c, arrays

**Issue overview **

The current issue i have is that i have an array which has the size of a variable which happens to be the amount of lines in a file. This is an integer which is calculated and returned, which becomes the arraysize (e.g. file text.txt has 12 lines so the array is of size 12).

I want to know how i can return this value to another c file for use in a function so i can loop through the complete array.

**points to note**

1. I am not allowed any globals at all in this assignment, no global arrays/variables at      all.
2. The line counting functions works correctly so i will not be posting it here
3. The array is set up correctly and print the correct results
4. Most of the code from the functions has been removed to make it easier to read.
5. The correct #includes for each file are present, i just need an example of how to do it.

The code:

```
void read_from_file() {
 /* reading and parsing removed */
no_of_lines = (count_lines(locof) - 1); 
/* locof is a char array storing the file name */

ship ships[no_of_lines];

 /* i want to return the value of no_of_lines *?
```

**I want to return the value of no_of_lines**

The c file where i need the value

```
 /*This is where i need the variable */
 void asign_mayday_to_ships() {

int* ship_arr_length = SIZE OF SHIP ARRAY NEEDED
mayday_call* mday_ptr;
ship* ship_ptr; /* this is a ship array */

mday_ptr = read_mayday_file();
ship_ptr = read_ship_locations();

int i;

for(i = 0; i < SIZE OF  SHIP ARRAY; i++){


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to first malloc my ships array, then set the size of the malloc depending on the amount of elements then i can return the size of the pointer:

```
ship* ships;
ships = malloc(sizeof (ship) * no_of_lines);
```

the in the function i was having trouble with:

```
mayday_call* mday_ptr;
ship* ship_ptr;

mday_ptr = read_mayday_file();
ship_ptr = read_ship_locations();

int arr_size = sizeof (ship_ptr)  ;
int i;
for(i =0; i < arr_size; i++) {
//do something
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Just pass both pointer and size, it'a a C way.

```
void read_from_file() {
 /* reading and parsing removed */
no_of_lines = (count_lines(locof) - 1); 
/* locof is a char array storing the file name */

ship ships[no_of_lines];

some_fun_from_second_file(ships, no_of_lines);
```

Comment: i forgot to add something, updated my post to include the function that needs the size is not allowed to take any parameters, its meant to test our problem solving update post to show function in question.

Answer (score 0):

Who calls the two fnctions? Can't you just return the nr of lines in an upper function then pass it in the second one? If not, then you must somehow store it in a variable(or a struct member) and then you can grab it later. This is a contextual solution, it might not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like your 'teacher' wants make you use a sentinel value. Ie put an object at the end of the array that cannot exist (a ship with name all spaces for example) then in the array processing you keep looping till you hit the magic value.

This is a bad design, but if you aren't allow globals and you aren't allow parameters I cant see what else to do